# Dagger 2 with Kotlin, returning type with generic in ApplicationComponent

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, dagger-2

I want to return type with generic to be exposed by sub-graphs, the problem is in auto-generated java-classes, I tried to do something, but the one way to solve it is to remove generic type from AppComponent and return simple object. Is there more "right" approach?

**Here is the AppComponent**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(activity: BaseActivity<MvpView, MvpPresenter<MvpView>>)

    //...
    fun dataBase(): Database<Realm>
}
```

**here is function in the ApplicationModule**

```
@Provides @Singleton fun provideDatabase(@AppContext context: App): Database<Realm> {
    Realm.init(context)
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name("db")
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
    return RealmDatabase(Realm.getDefaultInstance())
}
```

**Then I want to receive my Database**

```
@Provides @ActivityScope fun provideDich(database: Database<Realm>) = Someobject(database)
```

**And then I see log that says:**

```
**Error:com.test.data.storage.Database<? extends io.realm.Realm> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.**
```

**Because dagger2 generates factories like this and there is java masks**

```
    public final class Logout_Factory implements Factory<Logout> {
  private final MembersInjector<Logout> logoutMembersInjector;

  private final Provider<SessionStorage.CloudStorage> arg0Provider;

  private final Provider<Database<? extends Realm>> arg1Provider;

  public Logout_Factory(
      MembersInjector<Logout> logoutMembersInjector,
      Provider<SessionStorage.CloudStorage> arg0Provider,
      Provider<Database<? extends Realm>> arg1Provider) {
    assert logoutMembersInjector != null;
    this.logoutMembersInjector = logoutMembersInjector;
    assert arg0Provider != null;
    this.arg0Provider = arg0Provider;
    assert arg1Provider != null;
    this.arg1Provider = arg1Provider;
  }

  @Override
  public Logout get() {
    return MembersInjectors.injectMembers(
        logoutMembersInjector, new Logout(arg0Provider.get(), arg1Provider.get()));
  }

  public static Factory<Logout> create(
      MembersInjector<Logout> logoutMembersInjector,
      Provider<SessionStorage.CloudStorage> arg0Provider,
      Provider<Database<? extends Realm>> arg1Provider) {
    return new Logout_Factory(logoutMembersInjector, arg0Provider, arg1Provider);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out the solution.

You need to declare the `@JvmWildcard` in your `@Provide` method return type.

```
@Provides 
@Singleton 
fun provideDatabase(@AppContext context: App): Database<@JvmWildcard Realm> {
    Realm.init(context)
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name("db")
            .build()
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)
    return RealmDatabase(Realm.getDefaultInstance())
}
```