# Inject Generic types in Kotlin with Dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

In module

```
@Provides
@Named("test")
fun provideTest(): Factory<Cat> {
    return createdFactory
}
```

In activity

```
@Inject
@Named("test")
lateinit var mFactory: Factory<Cat>
```

In the end i get an error

> Error:(1, 1) Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations.
>   Please see the error messages above.

Comment: With NON-GENERIC types this code correctly work

Comment: Dagger doesn't do generic types.  You need a concrete type.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956303/5241933) i.e. by using the `@JVMWildcard` annotation in your `@Provides` method?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with injecting generic class. Below is my solution:

```
public class Bass<T>
```

next

```
open class Cat() : Bass<Cat>()
open class Dog() : Bass<Cat>()
```

finally

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Cat providesCat() {
    return new Cat() {
    };
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Dog providesDog() {
    return new Dog() {
    };
}
```

If something is stupid but it works - it is not stupid :D