# Dagger 2 Modules and generic parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

The question is if Dager 2 supports proper Generic parameters. I have the following test class:

```
@Module
class Test {

    @Provides
    fun t(
        l: List<String>,
        l1: List<Number> /* Error points to this dependency */
    ): String {

        return "String" + l + l1
    }

    @Provides
    fun list1(): List<Number>{
        throw Error()
    }

    @Provides
    fun list() : List<String> {
        throw Error()
    }
}
```

in the AppComponent I have usage

```
@Component(modules = [Test::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun str(): String
}
```

When I try to compile I got the following error:

> /AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Number> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
> public abstract interface AppComponent {
> ^
> java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Number> is injected at
> com.example.android.dagger.di.Test.t(…, l1)
> java.lang.String is requested at
> com.example.android.dagger.di.AppComponent.str()

The question is if Dagger support usage of generic parametered types in modules

**UPDATE**
As per @Jeff_Bowman answer, the convenient way of removing wildcards would be with usage on Kotlin `typealias`, like this:

```
typealias NumericList = List<@JvmSupressWildcards Number>

@Module
class Test {

    @Provides
    fun t(
        l: List<String>,
        l1: NumericList 
    ): String {

        return "String" + l + l1
    }

    @Provides
    fun list1(): NumericList{
        throw Error()
    }

    ........

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.util.List<**? extends java.lang.Number**> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Note the wildcard: [Kotlin defaults to using wildcards in a way that Java does not](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics). You can adjust those types using the [@JvmWildcard](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-wildcard/) and [@JvmSuppressWildcards](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-suppress-wildcards/) to ensure Dagger sees matching declarations.

You have your choice of whether the parameter has wildcards suppressed or whether your `@Provides` return value has wildcards added. The answer may depend on whether you expect most of your call sites to be Java versus Kotlin.

```
@Provides
fun t(
    l: List<String>,
    l1: List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Number>  // Note wildcard suppression
): String {
    return "String" + l + l1
}
```

See also:

- [Dagger in Kotlin: gotchas and Optimizations](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/dagger-in-kotlin-gotchas-and-optimizations-7446d8dfd7dc#:%7E:text=understand%20it%20properly.-,Injecting%20Generics,-Kotlin%20compiles%20generics) (Manuel Vivo, July 2019)
- [google/dagger#900: Kotlin+Dagger best practices/documentation/pain points](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/900#issuecomment-337065004) (comment by tasomaniac, October 2017)
- [Dagger 2 with Kotlin, returning type with generic in ApplicationComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566518/dagger-2-with-kotlin-returning-type-with-generic-in-applicationcomponent) (SO user Bisca, March 2017)